# iPhone - Image selection similar to Music Album in iPhone

Tags: iphone, image, selection, ipod

I am new in iPhone programming. I want to create a puzzle game and I would really like to implement and image selection screen similar to the way you select a Music Album in iPhone iPod.

I can't upload a picture, but I will send you a link if my description is not detailed enough.

I don't know what to search for details. Can you give me a hint if it is even possible to implement it?

Thank you a lot,
Andrei

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Refer to [this](https://github.com/devinross/tapkulibrary/tree/master/src/TapkuLibrary), it is much easier one.

Comment: Thank you. You've been really helpful. Sorry for my previous comment :D.

Answer (score 0):

That's called Cover Flow and there's an open source library that does something similar [here](http://www.chaosinmotion.com/flowcover.m).

Comment: Thank you a lot. I will try to integrate it in my project. 
Best Regards, Andrei

Comment: Still, is there another way, like an Apple predefined object or sample? Sorry if my questions are silly, I'm really new on this field.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, Apple has a built-in [UIImagePicker](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIImagePickerController_Class/UIImagePickerController/UIImagePickerController.html).

Comment: Hi Stephen,

Thank you. I wonder if the UIImagePicker can be used to behave like I described? The images that I was talking about are stored locally in the Main App Bundle.

Thank you

Comment: @Andrei, no, if you want that you'll have to implement one of the custom cover flows.